# Ruby on Rails + Rspec: Syntax for css selector containing instance variable

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have an rspec test where i need to specifically find a div block, from articles index page, corresponding to an article id and find the glyphicon representing a link to destroy/edit and article. I have a list of articles on the index page so i need to be specific for the css selector. However, i am unable to find a solution to do this. I have tried the below methods:

1) Add a id tag to each article in the article partial, and calling out the specific div using 'within'

**article partial:**

```
<div class = "row" id="<%= article.id %>" >
....more code....
</div>
```

**spec/features/article_spec.rb**

```
describe 'navigate' do

  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:article)  { FactoryGirl.create(:article) }

  before do
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  end

  describe 'edit' do

    before do
      @article_to_edit = Article.create(title: 'Article to edit', summary: 'Summary of article to edit', description: 'Test to edit this article', user_id: user.id)
    end

    it 'edit and delete icon is visible to article owner from index page' do
      visit articles_path
      within '#{@article_to_edit.id}' do
        expect(page).to have_css('.glyphicon-pencil')
        expect(page).to have_css('.glyphicon-trash')
      end

    end

end
```

**2) Substituting 'within' block with below code to find the specific href link of the article**

```
expect(page).to have_link('', href: "/articles/#{@article_to_edit.friendly_id}/edit")
expect(page).to have_link('', href: "/articles/#{@article_to_edit.friendly_id}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sting interpolation only works within strings with double quotes.

Just change

```
within '#{@article_to_edit.id}' do
```

to

```
within "#{@article_to_edit.id}" do
```

within the code example you posted in your question. And do the same at the places at which you build the URLs with `articles/#{@article_to_edit.friendly_id}...`

Comment: Hi,  thanks it works. i changed it to "#article_#{@article_to_edit.id}" to be more specific and prevent any problems with duplicate ids. I encounter another issue where because i created an instance variable article_to_edit in the 'before' statement, the article id increments with each test, meaning that i can't know for sure what is the actual article id used in that test. I thought that calling @article_to_edit.id would suffice.

Comment: i debugged by placing put page.html after visit_articles_path and i see that the css selector should be '#article_28', but the test prints out '#article_17"

Comment: The IDs of the records change depending on your database cleaner strategy and order in which your specs run (note that `random` is the default). Therefore you should not rely on specific ids. That said: What do you mean that the selector is `#article_17` when it should be `#article_28`. Why should it include the ID 28? How did you check?

Comment: I managed to fix it. I was careless and didn't specify the status of @article_to_edit variable, which defaults to draft and hence didn't appear on the articles index page. Now, the test passes. Another careless mistake was not removing some "put page.html" statements in other tests and making me confused with the ids. Actually, using "#article_#{@article_to_edit.friendly_id}" to print out the title strings instead of ids made things clearer for me.

Comment: Awesome. I am glad that I could help.